# What should i do if session logs out after "20" minutes in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have researched and implemented some codes to my project but still after 20 minutes, my session logs out and return to my login page. No matter how long I add timeout on `httpruntime` or `sessionstate` or in `global.asax` or increment the `Idle Timeout` in the IIS Application Pool, it doesn't seems to work.

web.config:

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="__authcookie" loginUrl="LoginPage.aspx" timeout="60" protection="All" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" enableCrossAppRedirects="false"/>
  </authentication>
  <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60" customProvider="AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider"></sessionState>
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider" type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheSessionStoreProvider" cacheName="NamedCache1" sharedId="SharedApp"/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
```

global.asax:

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs when a new session is started
            Session.Timeout = 60;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your `web.config` file

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms timeout="50"/>
    </authentication>
    <sessionState timeout="60"  />
</system.web>
```

Also if you don't want your session to be time out, you might interest in reading this article about [Avoid Prevent Session TimeOut In Asp.Net To Keep Alive](http://www.csharpaspnetarticles.com/2012/04/avoid-prevent-session-timeout-keepalive.html)

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the session that times out but the authentication. Authentication is controlled using the `<authentication>` element (.ASPXAUTH cookie by default), which is different from the session (Aspnet_SessionId cookie by default).

Use the `timeout` attribute of the `<authentication>` element.